# Accessing XBOX Narrator Settings from web driven XBOX App

Tags: uwp, xbox, narrator

I am working on an XBOX app that is UWP javascript driven. I need to access the systems narrator settings, but have not found any options.

Does anybody know of a way to access this information, or are there any manifest option capabilities to gain access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access the systems narrator settings, but have not found any options.

For accessing systems narrator setting, you could use [`launchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) method to launch [`ms-settings:easeofaccess-narrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#ease-of-access) setting scheme in UWP WinJS app. And you could using the following code directly.

```
document.getElementById("lanucherBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-settings:easeofaccess-narrator');
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    // Launch the URI with a warning prompt
    options.treatAsUntrusted = true;

    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri, options).then(
        function (success) {
            if (success) {

                // URI launched

            } else {

                // URI launch failed

            }
        });

});
```

**Update**

Currently, narrator does not provide api to check its state and use it with programming. If you want to if the narrator is active, you could use the above way to launch narrator setting page then check narrator's state.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you misunderstood though. I'm not trying to launch the accessibility page. I just want to get whatever current values (options) the user has set for the narrator, or check if the narrator is active.